# Java Annotations - Inheritance to avoid redundant annotations

Tags: java, annotations

I hope this is not a duplicate but I could not find a related question/answer for my requirement.

In the application, there is a requirement to apply spring caching annotations (which internally use ehcache) to many of the service layer's methods.

For example, the ContentService class has the following 2 methods.

```
@Caching(cacheable = { @Cacheable(condition = "#baseObj.isCacheEnabled()", value = "cacheName", key = "#baseObj.getCacheKey()") })
@Order(value = 2)
public ReturnObj getPageContent(BaseObject baseObj);

@Caching(cacheable = { @Cacheable(condition = "#baseObj.isCacheEnabled()", value = "cacheName", key = "#baseObj.getCacheKey()") })
@Order(value = 2)
public ReturnObj getModuleContent(BaseObject baseObj);
```

As you can see, the following annotations are repeated and redundant in every service method annotations.

```
@Caching(cacheable = { @Cacheable(condition = "#baseObj.isCacheEnabled()", value = "cacheName", key = "#baseObj.getCacheKey()") })
@Order(value = 2)
```

**Question1**
Is there a way I can extend the Caching annotation and move the redundant stuff there instead of littering the classes with the same code ?

For example,

```
@CustomCaching
@Order(value = 2)
public ReturnObj getPageContent(BaseObject baseObj);

@CustomCaching
@Order(value = 2)
public ReturnObj getModuleContent(BaseObject baseObj);
```

where CustomCaching interface can extend Spring's Caching interface and apply the commonly required annotations at one place.

**Question2**
Is there a way that I can specify `@Order(value=2)` at one common place and say, apply this annotation to all the methods within a class ?

Comment: Extending annotation is not possible , altough not exact duplicate however i guess what you demand is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607803/howto-extend-spring-annotation-transactional